# Execute Console Application with parameters from MVC 5 Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, upload

I have a MVC 5 controller and a C# console application executed like this:

```
lp c:\excel.xls /xls
```

I need to execute this line after I uploaded an XLS file using a Form:

```
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual JsonResult UploadXLS(HttpPostedFileBase XLSFile)
    {
        var uploadDir = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");

        if (XLSFile != null)
        {
            var originalFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(XLSFile.FileName);
            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + originalFileExtension;
            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadDir, fileName);

            XLSFilePartners.SaveAs(filePath);

            // EXECUTE THE CONSOLE PROJECT HERE

            return Json("Uploaded!", "text/html");
        }

        return Json("No File!", "text/html");
    }
```

Comment: Look at `Process.Start`.

Comment: @vesan: Comment up-voted. Make this an answer with a short example please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a program, you can use `Process.Start`. You will need to supply the path to the executable and the parameters:

```
Process.Start("lp.exe", "c:\\excel.xls /xls");
```

If your command line arguments contain spaces (like the file path), you will need to enclose them in quotation marks (and escape those, since it is a string). Like this:

```
"\"c:\\path with spaces\\excel.xls\" /xls"
```

Note that this will only start the process - it doesn't wait until it's finished. If you need that, look at `Process.WaitForExit`.

For more info look at the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hi, thanks! It's working fine. It was not necessary to take care of the spaces, I put " /xls" in the parameters and it's working fine ;)